# how to return null using findbyvalue of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

this is my code

```
string result = ddllist.FindByValue(lstvalueA).Text;
```

if there is no `lstvalueA` in `ddllist`,null should be assigned to `result`

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if it's `null`:

```
string result = null;
ListItem item = ddllist.Items.FindByValue(lstvalueA);
if(item != null)
    result = item.Text;
```